# Help needed to solve 1st order Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The weight w(t) of an individual  fish at  time  t is governed by the differential equation

$ \frac{dw}{dt} = \alpha w^{2/3} - \beta w$

Initial condition $ w(0) = w_{0}$ (the weight at birth), and where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are positive parameters depending on the  fish species.
 Without solving the differential equation, determine $lim_{t-> \infty} w(t)$

Now solve the differential equation explicitly and show that
 $ w = \frac{1}{\beta^{3}}(\alpha-(\alpha-\beta w_{0}^{1/3}) e^{\beta/3})^{3}$

I am not sure how to do the first part, of the limit problem. so if anyone can suggest a way?

Also for the second part,I am not able to get the exact expression...

let u = w^1/3

$ du = \frac{1}{3} w^{-2/3}$

$ \frac{1}{w^{-2/3}} \frac{dw}{dt} = \alpha - \beta u $

$ \frac{3du}{dt} = \alpha - \beta u $

$ \int \frac{3}{\alpha - \beta u}  = \int dt$

I am not sure 'how' to integrate the fraction part? Do I use another u-substitution?

Comment: The first part asks you to draw a phase diagram of this differential equation and to deduce from this diagram, without computing the solutions, that for every $w_0>0$, $w(t)\to(\beta/\alpha)^3$.

Comment: Re the second part, are you sure you cannot find a primitive $$\int\frac{du}{\alpha-\beta u}\ ?$$

Comment: I am not sure what yo mean?

Comment: @italy Following on from Dids comment,

$$\int \frac{du}{\alpha - \beta u} = \frac{-1}{\beta} \int \frac{-\beta}{\alpha - \beta u} du$$

Hopefully you can see how to integrate this now. **Alternatively**, if you are more familiar with substitutions, make the substitution $v = \alpha - \beta u \implies - dv/\beta = du$.

Comment: $ -\frac{1}{\beta} ln(\alpha-\beta w^{1/3}) = t+c$ , is this correct? Frome here If I put in the initial condiction,  $-\frac{1}{\beta} ln(\alpha-\beta w^{1/3}) -c = w_{0}$ but than when I put this back into the equation the two expressions cancel? I dont get the bove w = epression